# Setting constructor variables with outside method inside of the same class

Tags: java, class, methods, constructor

I'm trying to send `asteroid1`-`asteroid10` to sandbox inside of the `AsteroidField()` constructor. I am not able to simply write `sandbox.addBlob(asteroid1);` in `generate()` because I am now outside of the constructor. How can I work around this?

```
public class AsteroidField implements BlobGUI {
    private static Random random = new Random();

    public AsteroidField() {
        SandBox sandbox = new SandBox();
        sandbox.setSandBoxMode(FLOW);
        sandbox.setFrameRate(15);
        sandbox.init(this);
    }

    public void generate() {
        int z;
        int i;
        int[] x = new int[10];
        int[] y = new int[10];
        double[] r = new double[10];

        for( i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
            x[i] = 0;
            while( x[i] == 0 )
                x[i] = random.nextInt(7) - 3;
            y[i] = 0;
            while( y[i] == 0 )
                y[i] = random.nextInt(7) - 3;
            r[i] = 0;
            while( r[i] == 0 ) {
                z = random.nextInt();
                if( z % 2 == 0 )
                    r[i] = -0.1;
                else
                    r[i] = 0.1;   
            }
        }

        i = 0;
        Asteroid asteroid1 = new Asteroid( x[i], y[i], r[i] );

        i++;
        Asteroid asteroid2 = new Asteroid( x[i], y[i], r[i] );
        i++;
        Asteroid asteroid3 = new Asteroid( x[i], y[i], r[i] );
        i++;
        Asteroid asteroid4 = new Asteroid( x[i], y[i], r[i] );
        i++;
        Asteroid asteroid5 = new Asteroid( x[i], y[i], r[i] );
        i++;
        Asteroid asteroid6 = new Asteroid( x[i], y[i], r[i] );
        i++;
        Asteroid asteroid7 = new Asteroid( x[i], y[i], r[i] );
        i++;
        Asteroid asteroid8 = new Asteroid( x[i], y[i], r[i] );
        i++;
        Asteroid asteroid9 = new Asteroid( x[i], y[i], r[i] );
        i++;
        Asteroid asteroid10 = new Asteroid( x[i], y[i], r[i] );
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `generate()` called from, from inside or outside the class? Why is it a separate method from the constructor?

Answer (score 1):

Keep `SandBox` object in class.

```
SandBox sandbox;
public AsteroidField() {

    sandbox = new SandBox();
    sandbox.setSandBoxMode(FLOW);
    ...
```

Comment: @hunter3035, please consider accepting the answer as correct if it helps you.